# Isomorphism between two graphs $Q, R$

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I am unable to prove or disprove that these graphs are isomorphic. Let $X, Y$ be the "lowest" points on the left graph and $X', Y'$ on the right (in that order). I tried to set $f(X) = Y', f(Y) = X'$ to unwrap the graph, but then I lose the neighborhood property.

They are both regular, non-bipartite, have same radius (2) and diametar (3), longest and shortest cylic subgraphs have lenghts of 4 and 9 in both of them, etc.

I would appreciate the answer.

Comment: You have two possibilities: to try to prove they are isomorphic, or to try to prove they are not isomorphic.  What techniques do you know?  Which of them have you tried?  (What you describe as your prior effort is basically "I spent five minutes and the first thing I tried didn't work, please do my homework for me", not exactly inspiring.)

Comment: Also these are not "cyclic graphs"

Comment: I included my work in the question.

Comment: Where is the 4-cycle you found in the graph on the left?  I don't see one.

Comment: Oh, blunder. Thank you!